# Why just some images appear in my github README?

Tags: git, github, markdown

I recently visited my GitHub profile and noticed that some images in my README have disappeared. When I initially created it, everything was working perfectly fine. However, now only a few images are showing up, and I'm unsure why. Can anyone provide assistance with this issue?

Thank you!

https://github.com/GuilOliveira/GuilOliveira

I removed the images from a server, and put it in the repo. But still didnt worked :(

Comment: Do you mean there are some image links in the text content of the README file that do not appear as images when viewing the repo home page?

Comment: Or do you mean that some text content has just mysteriously disappeared from the README file?

Comment: Yes, I have several gifs in the readme, but some of them stopped appearing on GitHub (they still appear in VSCode). However, the links were working, and the gifs were up.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that it wraps *.gif* images into `<animated-image>` (some sort of a *.gif* player, with a Play button). So it sets **display:none** on images that couldn't be wrapped for some reason (for example your image inside `<h1>` tag).

Try without `<h1>` (as it also creates a wrapper `<a>` link that probably breaks the *.gif* player's click events). Also you can check the result with your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Hey, I removed the h1 and the first gif appeared, thanks!

After struggling a little I figured out what was happening!